# What C version does Borland Turbo C 2.01 use?

Tags: c, turbo-c

I've started working with Turbo C 2.01 as a hobby project. Yes, the DOS version. Since it came out in 1987, I assume it doesn't support C90... except it does. Well, pieces of it. The `volatile` keyword works. And straight K&R isn't supported; I tried K&R style declarations, to an error.

So, I was wondering what form of C Turbo C uses. I'm sure it's nonstandard, but it seems somewhat consistent, and since this was a very popular compiler back in the day, I'm sure there's some collection of information... right?

Comment: I'm also aware that `near` and `far` are nonstandard. That does not concern me. Mmm... pointer juggling...

Comment: Draft of C89............?

Comment: It probably supports "the Borland Turbo C 2.01 version". Turbo C *is* a form of C.

Comment: From what I remember, it is "almost C90". It had some minor standard compliance issues here and there. (Unlike TC++ 3.0 which is just completely bananas if you compare it with the standard. And no wonder, since it was released 8 years before C++98 standardization.)

Comment: You should stop using this obsolete piece of software anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was no real standard back then, and additionally MS-DOS had its own quirks (namely the segmented memory model, and different application memory models using them differently...).

So I think it's safe to say, Turbo C 2.01 uses Turbo C 2.01 dialect of C.

About supporting C90, note that the standard obviously did its best to have existing C code be compatible with it. So it's not surprising Turbo C from 87 can build most C90 programs with minimal changes.

Answer (score 4):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)), original K&R non standard spec came out in 78. The starting point of the ANSI X3J11 committee that produced the ANSI C89 standard is 1983, and the goal was

> to establish a standard specification of C. X3J11 based the C standard on the Unix implementation.

That standard was then adopted by ISO as C90. But as it was extensively based on an existing implementation, the extensions from this implementation were already ported in other implementations like Borland's one.

So there is no real suprise that Borland C2.01 from 87 already includes most of the extensions to K&R C that has been adopted in standard only 2 years later.